# Display text file 5 lines at a time in Perl

Tags: perl

I'm not sure how to do this.

I have a file (which will never be large, so won't need a module) and want to break it down so that I can display it on my web page 5 lines per row.

This is as far as I have got.

```
$row="5";
@DD=<DATA>;
foreach $line (@DD) {
$count++;
chomp($line);
 if ($count <= $row) {
 print qq~$line ~; # This shows5, but don't know what to do next.
 }
}
exit;


__DATA__
aaaa
bbbb
cccc
dddd
eeee
ffff
gggg
hhhh
iiii
jjjj
kkkk
llll
mmmm
```

Expected result (should be in 3 line but your forum software won't let me)

```
aaaa bbbb cccc dddd eeee
ffff gggg hhhh iiii jjjj
kkkk llll mmmm
```

Could someone help please?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! If you need a hand in understanding a part of the site, might I recommend the tour? http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 3):

You'd have to reset the count and print a new line at 5.

```
 print qq~$line~;
 if ( $count == $row ) { 
     print "\n";
     $count = 0;
 }
 else { 
     print ' ';
 }
```

However, easier still is a modulus:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $row   = 5;
my $count = 0;

foreach my $line ( <DATA> ) { 
    chomp( $line );
    print $line, ++$count % $row ? ' ' : "\n";
}
```

If `$count` is a multiple of `$row` print a newline, else print a space.

Comment: Axeman, I've used your contribution thanks - works a treat. I can't post the code it seems (this forum software sucks).

Comment: @Gris, Thanks. You could mark it as the answer and get a little rep for us both (IIRC)

Answer (score 1):

When you reach the limit (5) reset the counter to 0 and print a newline

```
$count = 0;
print "\n";
```

BTW there are a number of improvements you could do to your code, but the most important would be to [use strict and warnings](http://perlmaven.com/always-use-strict-and-use-warnings)

I think this will work:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $rows = 5;
my $count = 0;
my @lines = <DATA>;
chomp @lines;
foreach my $line (@lines) {
    $count++;
    if ($count <= $rows) {
        print qq{$line };
    } else {
        $count = 0;
        print "\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many problems with your code. See my comments below.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $threshold = 5;

my @buffer;
while (my $line = <DATA>) {
    $line =~ s/\s\z//;
    push @buffer, $line;
    if (@buffer % $threshold == 0) {
        print join(' ', @buffer), "\n";
        @buffer = ();
    }
}

@buffer
    and print join(' ', @buffer), "\n";

__DATA__
aaaa
bbbb
cccc
dddd
eeee
ffff
gggg
hhhh
iiii
jjjj
kkkk
llll
mmmm
```

Here is a list of things you should think about:

First, You should use [strict](https://metacpan.org/pod/strict) and [warnings](https://metacpan.org/pod/warnings).

> $row="5";

`$row` is intended to be used as numeric variable. Why assign a string to it?

> ```
> @DD=<DATA>;
> foreach $line (@DD) {
> ```

No need to create an extra array by slurping, of all things, your `__DATA__` section. Instead, use `while` and read line-by-line.

> ```
> $count++;
> ```

Perl's builtin [$.](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlvar) counts the number of lines read. No need for an additional variable.

For variety: If you insist on slurping, you can slurp into a string:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $threshold = 5;
my $contents = do { local $/; <DATA> };

while ($contents) {
    ($contents, my @fields) = reverse split(qr{\n}, $contents, $threshold + 1);
    print join(' ', reverse @fields), "\n";
}
```

or, continue to slurp into an array and use `splice`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $threshold = 5;
my @contents = <DATA>;

while (@contents) {
    print join(' ', map { chomp; $_ } splice @contents, 0, $threshold), "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# always start your Perl 5 files with these
# two pragmas until you know exactly why they
# are recommended
use strict;
use warnings;

my $row = 5;

while ( <> ){
    chomp;
    print;

    print $. % $row ? ' ' : "\n";
}

# makes sure there is always a trailing newline
print "\n" if $. % $row;
```

```bash
$ time ./example.pl /usr/share/dict/words

...

real    0m2.217s
user    0m0.097s
sys     0m0.084s
```

In Perl 6 I would probably write it as:

```perl6
'filename'.IO.lines.rotor(5, :partial).map: *.say;
```

( currently takes about 15 seconds to process `/usr/share/dict/words` under the Moar backend, but it hasn't had 20 years of optimizations applied to it like Perl 5 has. It may be faster with the JVM backend )